# cannot get json attribute

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get all the name attributes from the JSON below using JavaScript?

```
{
  "layerGroup": {
    "name": "tasmania",
    "mode": "SINGLE",
    "title": "Tasmania",
    "abstractTxt": "Tasmania Australia from Digital Chart of the World.",
    "publishables": {
      "published": [{
        "@type": "layer",
        "name": "tasmania_state_boundaries",
        "href": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_state_boundaries.json"
      }, {
        "@type": "layer",
        "name": "tasmania_water_bodies",
        "href": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_water_bodies.json"
      }, {
        "@type": "layer",
        "name": "tasmania_roads",
        "href": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_roads.json"
      }, {
        "@type": "layer",
        "name": "tasmania_cities",
        "href": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tasmania_cities.json"
      }]
    },
    "styles": {
      "style": ["null", "null", "null", "null"]
    },
    "bounds": {
      "minx": 143.83482400000003,
      "maxx": 148.47914100000003,
      "miny": -43.648056,
      "maxy": -39.573891,
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "entry": {
        "@key": "rawStyleList",
        "$": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: alert(data.layerGroup.name;) prints only tasmania i want all name attibute

Comment: You can use Object.keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you wanted?
You need to loop `layerGroup.publishables.published` and get the name.

```js
var data = {"layerGroup":{"name":"tasmania","mode":"SINGLE","title":"Tasmania","abstractTxt":"Tasmania Australia from Digital Chart of the World.","publishables":{"published":[{"@type":"layer","name":"tasmania_state_boundaries","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_state_boundaries.json"},{"@type":"layer","name":"tasmania_water_bodies","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_water_bodies.json"},{"@type":"layer","name":"tasmania_roads","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_roads.json"},{"@type":"layer","name":"tasmania_cities","href":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/tasmania_cities.json"}]},"styles":{"style":["null","null","null","null"]},"bounds":{"minx":143.83482400000003,"maxx":148.47914100000003,"miny":-43.648056,"maxy":-39.573891,"crs":"EPSG:4326"},"metadata":{"entry":{"@key":"rawStyleList","$":""}}}};

for (var i =0; i<data.layerGroup.publishables.published.length; i++){
console.log(data.layerGroup.publishables.published[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write foreach loop for every item in`published`. 
Instead of `alert(data.layerGroup.name);`
You need to access published object and its 'name'attribute.
Right now you are accessing th 'name' attribute of 'layerGroup'